# Executing webpack failed with exit code 1 when trying ns run ios after running ns migrate

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I ran the following `ns migrate` per the documentation to update my app to use the latest version of NativeScript. It succeeds

```
⚠ Git branch not clean, but using --force
✔ Pre-Migration verification complete
✔ Project files have been backed up
✔ Cleaned directory hooks
✔ Cleaned directory platforms
✔ Cleaned directory node_modules
✔ Cleaned file webpack.config.js
✔ Cleaned file package-lock.json
ℹ Skipping tsconfig.tns.json because it doesn't exist.
✔ Project files have been cleaned up
✔ Cleaned old artifacts
ℹ Skipping app/package.json because it doesn't exist.
ℹ Skipping nsconfig.json because it doesn't exist.
✔ Project has been migrated to use nativescript.config.ts
  - nativescript-dev-webpack has been replaced with @nativescript/webpack v3.0.0
  - nativescript-angular has been replaced with @nativescript/angular v10.0.0
✔ Project dependencies have been updated
✔ Updated tsconfig.json
✔ Migration complete.

Project has been successfully migrated. The next step is to run ns run <platform> to ensure everything is working properly.

Please note that ns migrate does not make changes to your source code, you may need additional changes to complete the migration
```

This succeeded okay as seen above. I note that nativescript-dev-webpack was replaced with @nativescript/webpack v3.0.0

I then run `ns run ios` and continually get the following error:

```
Platform ios successfully added. v7.0.0
Preparing project...
/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                throw err;
                ^

TypeError: host.onUnRecoverableConfigFileDiagnostic is not a function
    at Object.getParsedCommandLineOfConfigFile (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:27947:18)
    at getCompilerOptionsFromTSConfig (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/utils/tsconfig-utils.js:14:25)
    at getNoEmitOnErrorFromTSConfig (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/utils/tsconfig-utils.js:20:29)
    at module.exports (/Users/iosdev/appdir/webpack.config.js:104:39)
    at handleFunction (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prepareOptions.js:21:13)
    at prepareOptions (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:117:14)
    at /Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/iosdev/appdir/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

From reading that error I understand that it might possibly something to do with webpack being up upgraded to version 3.0.0 as mentioned above. Can someone assist me deciphering this error log output as I've not been able to find a similar issue on SO or the web. I did review some others who had the same "Executing webpack failed with exit code 1." but those didn't quite match up with my scenario.

Thank you!